# objects are not null and exception is still raised

Tags: c#, invoke

Answer: it was in the else code, but I thought there is no reason that code wouldn't point to that line.

Can someone offer an idea how it could be possible that I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this at Invoke method:

```
delegate void t(tabdescriptor tab);
internal void AddItem(tabdesciptor tab)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        t inv = new t(AddItem);
        if (inv != null && tab!= null)
            Invoke(inv, tab);
    }
    else
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your call stack at the time of the exception?

Comment: That code won't compile, for a start. You can't create a delegate from just an object as you've tried to with `new t(o)`. Please give a short but *complete* example.

Comment: what is the value of `tab`? It seems that this is never set

Comment: what line the exception is thrown?

Comment: OK, I've updated code. In the original code it is not object, but an object called tabdescriptor. Anyway, it is not null.

Comment: I can't find anything specific in call stack. The thread from which it is called is non-gui thread, so Invoke is required

Comment: Have you ruled out `something.AddItem(t)` where `something` is null? Have you ruled out the else clause as the location of the exception?

Comment: `t inv = new t(tab);` is still nonsense, please post something that compiles.

Comment: You are right. I though it would be better to make names more generic, but made two errors in doing that... But the problem I talked about exists.

Comment: Ivan: Your problem may be real but your code is not...

Comment: -1 If you can't or won't paste your real code then develop a prototype project to demonstrate your problem and make sure that replicates your failing behavior. Making up fake code is just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: it is in the else code, but had no idea that it would look like this, so I didn't write else code here. Other code is exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the actual issue is considering your example cannot be the code that executes, but please try something like this:

```
internal void AddItem(tabdesciptor tab)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<tabdescriptor>(AddItem), tab);
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Also please make sure that it's not actually whatever is in the `else` part that fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, it raises the same exception.

Comment: @Ivan: and you are __sure__ it's not the `else` part that fails?

Comment: It is the else part, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this exception could be coming from inside the invoked method. If you place a try/catch inside the else of the `AddItem` method and a breakpoint inside the catch, do you catch the exception?

```
internal void AddItem(tabdesciptor tab)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        t inv = new t(AddItem);
        if (inv != null && tab!= null)
            Invoke(inv, tab);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            ....
        }
        catch
        {
            // breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, but I think the answer above was first, so I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether it's a mistake in the given example, or not, but `tab` is never checked for `null`, yet it is passed as the argument.

Either it's probably `null`, or:

Also, `inv` is checked for `null` right after creating it (Good in C/C++, but unnecessary in C# as it throws an [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) upon failure), but it is done before checking `o` for `null`.

Comment: No, I've updated, I just switched tab to o to be more generic, but forgot one instance.

Comment: `tab` is still unchecked, and now `o` is undeclared but still checked for `null`.

Comment: OK, I've updated in the browser instead of using find and replace and forgot one instance. But it is checked.